# Auto-Scroll DIV, but only, if user's not scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, scroll

Experts,

I've a problem scrolling a div / panel. I developed an ASPX application, displaying some messages in a panel. The panel is child of an update panel control. In it, there's a timer, which updates the message display every second and scrolls the panel to bottom.
Take a loog at the code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="udpnlMessages" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function scrollPanelToBottom() {
                    $('#<%=pnlMessagesOverview.ClientID %>').scrollTop($('#<%=pnlMessagesOverview.ClientID %>')[0].scrollHeight);
            }

        </script>
        <asp:Timer runat="server" Interval="1000" ID="tmrCheckNewMessages" Enabled="True" OnTick="TmrCheckNewMessagesOnTick"></asp:Timer>
        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlMessagesOverview" CssClass="messageScrollPanel">

        </asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The JS function is registered on prerender handler of my panel.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// pre render handler
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The sender.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The <see cref="EventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
    protected void PnlMessagesOverviewOnPreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
            this.pnlMessagesOverview,
            this.pnlMessagesOverview.GetType(),
            "scrollPanelToBottom",
            "scrollPanelToBottom();",
            true);
    }
```

That's working fine so far. Problem is: If the user scrolls up, because he's reading some older messages, this JS kicks him to the bottom of the panel every second. So I have to prevent the auto-scroll, if the user scrolled manually up.

And: I've no idea how to implement that. I tried some JS scroll handlers.. But i could not find a solution matching my desired behaviour... :(

Anyone out there, who can help me with that?

Comment: You can turn off the automated scrolling once the user has scrolled up manually.. But how do you determine, that the user has finished reading other stuff, and want the automated scroll when message at the bottom is updated??

Comment: You could do something like check if the scroll is not at the bottom, if it is add your content, if it's not pop up a small link, "you have new messages, click to view", which on clicking scrolls to the bottom.